# subview of UIWebview is not responding to load request

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am building a web browser that creates a new UIWebview when I add another tab.Each new view is given a tag upon creation which allows me to call a specific view. When I call the subview to front it does not respond to a load request. This is how I am bringing the subview to the front

```
-(void) selectionMade:(id)sender
{
    //find view with same tag num as button pushed
   for (UIView *view in self.webView.subviews)
    {
        if (view.tag == [sender tag])
        {
            [self.webView bringSubviewToFront:view];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for responding to the text field that I enter the address into.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    NSString *text = [textField.text lowercaseString];

    if (![text hasPrefix:@"http://"] && ![text hasPrefix:@"https://"])
    {
        text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", text];
    }

    self.title = text;
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:text];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly timeoutInterval:10.];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Comment: You have a webview and add other webviews as subviews of the webview? This is a bad behavior. You are sending your load requests to only one webview, but if you have another webview on top of it as a subview, it will hide the superview webview, which is actually loading.

Comment: should I have created a new view controller as I add tabs?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on the experience you want to provide. You could also create a webview for each tab, but they should be on the same level in the hierarchy (same superview), and you just move them to the front. This is what Safari does. I'll type an answer with options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be adding other webviews as subviews of your webview. This is an incorrect design. Practically, what happens is you call `loadRequest:` on the main webview, but bring one of its subviews to front, which hides the main webview's content.

Depending on the experience you want to provide, you have several options.

1. You can juggle webviews (similar to what you wanted to do here). But
   these webviews should be on the same level in the hierarchy, and
   they should only be brought to front as needed. Your view controller
   will then be the delegate of multiple webviews and will have to
   service them all. This is how Safari manages its views.
2. You can create a page view controller and feed it different view controllers for each tab. This will make it more easier to manage, as each view controller will only service one tab. It will also allow you to offer a swipe from left or right to quickly switch tabs.